# Orchard cms custom form customize

Tags: orchardcms

I created a custom form, and adding the fields in a specific order. The form is like a questionnaire wherein the next question is a follow-up of the previous question(s) above it. But right now I am trying to put some of the questions side by side instead of one question follow-up the previous one. Can someone tell me how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Orchard.DynamicForms module to build your custom form?

If so you should find the Layout category down the right hand side:

[image]

Choose `Row (2 columns)` to create a special row with two columns side-by-side. You can then put your form elements inside of it.

Otherwise you are going to need to explain a bit more clearly as to what Orchard version and what module/approach you are using to create this form.